# JavaScript function call not working in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, function, call

have some problems here.
Seems only to fail in IE 8 (or 7 too).
I would be happy if you help me.

```
$.ajax({type: "POST",
     url:"update_data.php",
     data: {
            table:table,
            key:key,
            obj_name:"New Element"                                  
           },
           success: function(data){
           $('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
           $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');
           $.get("get_process.php", {
                    func: "software",
                    selected: "All_Software"
           }, function(response){
              $('#result_software').fadeOut();
              setTimeout("finishAjax_software('result_software', '"+escape(response)+"')", 400);
                       })
              return false;
                            }
                    });updateSelect('software');
```

here the code of the updateSelect:

```
function updateSelect(id){
            $('#'+id).html(''); 
            $.get("get_process.php", {
                    options: id,
                }, 
                function(response){
                    $('#'+id).fadeOut();
                    setTimeout("finishAjax_"+id+"('"+id+"', '"+escape(response)+"')", 1000);
            })    
        }
```

So the updateSelect call does not work in IE 8. Help me please

Comment: looks good to me, could it be the extra (but legal) trailing comma in line *options: id,*

Comment: thank, you're right! i seem to be blind after hundret of code lines :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
   function updateSelect(id){
        $('#'+id).html(''); 
        $.get("get_process.php", {
                options: id     // <-- remove trailing comma
            }, 
            function(response){
                $('#'+id).fadeOut();
                setTimeout("finishAjax_"+id+"('"+id+"', '"+escape(response)+"')", 1000);
            }
        )    
    }
```